# Access Azure cloud File Shares in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-appservice, azure-file-share

We have created an ASP.Net Web API project and deployed it into the Azure App service. We have an Azure storage account and File Shares.

Can we mount this File share to App Service?

Comment: Please refer this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/22eb729d-a512-4a2c-b05c-22d570752be8/mounting-file-share-in-an-app-service?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview to mount app service and file share using powershell

Answer (score 0):

In the Web App left menu, click on **Configuration** and then, on the **Path Mappings** tab. Click on **New Storage Mount**. You can mount Blob and Files storage.